# stylePreprocessorOptions for libraries, where should I put in in angular.json?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use `stylePreprocessorOptions` in order to include a path to my variables folders **for a library project** like so :

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "styles/variables"
  ]
}
```

Then I use `@import 'colors';` within the scss file. But it doesnt work while doing `ng serve` :

```
@import 'colors';
       ^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

Here is the full library in angular.json :

```
        "ui-table": {
            "root": "libs/ui/table",
            "sourceRoot": "libs/ui/table/src",
            "projectType": "library",
            "prefix": "xxx",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "libs/ui/table/tsconfig.lib.json",
                        "project": "libs/ui/table/ng-package.json",
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "styles/variables"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": ["libs/ui/table/tsconfig.lib.json"],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "schematics": {
                "@nrwl/schematics:component": {
                    "styleext": "scss"
                }
            }
        },
```

How can I use `stylePreprocessorOptions` in a library in Angular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not in angular.json.

Include the path to your *scss* folder with `styleIncludePaths` in the librairies' ng-package.json

```
"lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    ...
    "styleIncludePaths": [
        "relative/path/to/scss/folder"
    ]
    ...
}
```

finally import the files from the referenced *scss* folder without prefix path as follows

```
@import "filename";
```

Comment: @GreatHawkeye please accept this as the correct answer if it has solved your issue like mine.

Comment: I have a showcase app to test my library, the application cannot find the scss file in the styleIncludePaths.  The library itself builds just fine.  But its like the scss file is not included in the bundle

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me using Angular v9.

But this did:

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "styleIncludePaths": ["./src/assets/styles"]
    }
  }
}
```

More details here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/style-include-paths.md

Answer (score 0):

I have a library upgraded to Angular 12, compiled with ng-packagr, but also having a demo project inside (ie. a mini-application showing off the components).
We use dart-sass (default for Angular now).

I had deep imports like: `@import '../../../../layout/src/lib/form-label.mixins';`

I just replaced them with `@import 'layout/src/lib/form-label.mixins';` and it worked,
where `layout` is at the root of the project: the library is made of sub-bundles.

I tried that because Angular didn't like to have `styleIncludePaths` declared in `angular.json`, and we don't have `ng-package.json` in our projects.

Note: IIRC, it didn't work in previous versions of Angular.